# Visual Studio 2012 Customize Pending Changes Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to create a checkin policy for Visual Studio 2012. It should be possible for developers to ignore the policy violation (yes, I have a use case for this) by some checkbox or something. For this I need to adjust the Pending Changes Window (adding the checkbox and maybe some text). Do some of you know if and how this can be done? Or some other possibility to achieve this goal?

Thanks,
Johannes

Comment: If you do not meet the checkin policiy you should be asked by the TFS anyway to override it. Do you just want to replace that window confirmation with a checkbox?

Comment: I didn't know that you can override the policy already, didn't create a policy yet. That would be enough to solve my problem. It still would be better to be able to add a checkbox or something in the Pending Changes window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a checkbox but there is already UI to override built in policies what may be used with custom policies too.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that would also be enough. Thanks